# Goodman furnance Air pressure switch - faulty?

Tags: hvac

I have at least a 10 year old Goodman gas Furnance.  The past couple of days the burner and blower did not come on.  I do not see any indicator lights come on.  The inducer comes on, but nothing else. I took the air pressure switch out and blew air into it and the air hose. I reinstalled the switch and everything worked fine.  I've done this twice in two or three days.

My question is - does this seem like a faulty air pressure switch or is it an indication of a bigger problem?  I can easily buy and swap out the switch which would tell me the answer, but before spending $25 on the switch - I thought I'd ask here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the switch is sticking, which is a sign that it's time to swap it out.

Before you do, though, make sure the exhaust and condensate drain aren't blocked/restricted.

$25 is a fairly cheap test, unless you have a gauge on hand to check the pressure.